# Send push notification when user visited website Azure/Android

Tags: android, azure

I would like to have push notification when a user visit my website.
I have an Android's app registered and working for push notification but I can't find a way to send push notification when a user visit my website.

Is is it possible? Can you help me?

Thanks,
Regards,
Mafyou.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: I followed the push notification getting started provided by MSDN.
I would like to have push notification when user visit my website. I don't know how to achieve that.
Have you got guidelines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, your App back-end needs to store the Registration Token which is returned from the relevant notification service when the client app decides it wants to receive push notifications, and your app back-end needs to manage the registrations. In order to send the notification, your app back-end needs to communicate with notification service (FCM/GCM) using the registration token to target a specific client app.

> I would like to have push notification when user visit my website. I don't know how to achieve that. Have you got guidelines?

Based on your requirement, your app back-end needs to store the Registration Token along with a specific user. I would use [Azure Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-overview) for sending notifications instead of building back-end for managing the registrations. For Android Apps, you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started) for getting started with Azure Notification Hubs. When registering with Azure Notification hubs, you could leverage [Routing and tag expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-tags-segment-push-message) and store the notification registration with the associate tags (e.g. user unique identity,etc). When your application monitored that a user visited your website, you could use the Azure Notification Hubs server SDKs to send notification against the specific user tag.